# Existence of dominating, monotone decreasing square summable series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose $\{a_i\}_{i\in\Bbb N}$ is an $\ell^2$ sequence. Does there necessarily exist a monotone decreasing sequence $\{b_i\}_{i\in\Bbb N}$ in $\ell^2$ with $b_k \geq |a_k|$ for all $k$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. To construct a counterexample think of a sequence which is non-zero only very rarely (with increasing distances).

Say $a_{2^n}=1/n$ and $a_i=0$ if $i$ is not a power of $2.$ Then $\{a_i\}\in \ell^2.$ Now assume there is a monotone decreasing sequence $\{b_i\}$ with $b_i \geq |a_i|$ for all $i.$ Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{i=2^{n-1}}^{2^n} b_i^2 \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{i=2^{n-1}}^{2^n} |a_{2^n}|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{n-1}}{n^2},
$$
which clearly diverges, so $\{b_i\}\notin \ell^2.$